# Ant scp command with permissions

Tags: ant, scp

I am working with ANT 'SCP' command but it doesn't retain the permission on SCP. So I thought I would use SCP on unix machine as executable as work around but I am wondering how I set the password on exec command? Any ideas on How work on it?

```
    <exec executable="scp" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-r"/>
        <arg value="tcbuild@pghlinux6:${checkoutDir}/Package/"/>
        <arg value="/licregs.140"/>
    </exec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got away with this one in ANT. By Using sshexec to remotely change permissions and using SCP command.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an authorized key.  If the key is authorized, then you don't need the password.  If the key has a password you can use ssh-agent to retain a copy of the decripted key.

Answer (score 0):

There's an ant bug open for the fact that the scp hardcodes the permissions of the created files. If sshexec isn't an option, there's a patch attached to the bug which could be applied to your local ant which allows scp to take chmod and umask options, like the ftp task does.